# content from a spinner to a text view

Tags: java, android, textview, android-spinner

I have a spinner and I would like the item selected by the spinner to go into a text view beside it. Here's my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner sp1;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                        String val = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        txt.setText(val);
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
               });
    }
```

Comment: Is this code working?

Comment: yes it is but it just put the item at the top of the spinner not in a text view I dont know how to do more than that

Answer (score 0):

You should post xml code of layout also. Check where is your TextView in layout (Graphical Layout).
See code below:

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/spnr"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner spinner;
TextView textView;
String[] items = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnr);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()); 
            // You can use your array also:
            // textView.setText(items[position]);   
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

}
```